# Finding the rank of a matrix using gauss jordan method

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the rank of the matrix \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}

After reducing it to row echelon form I got as follows
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

**My Conclusion**

Since there are $3$ non-zero rows, the rank of the matrix is $3$

Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: The rank can be seen from the row echelon form. Here it is obvioulsly $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the matrix indeed happens to have rank $3$, but the reasoning to get to that conclusion is a bit more complicated than what you've done.

Let's being with your manipulated matrix.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

After adding the second row to the first, and subtracting two times the third row from the first, we get

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Since this shows that all three rows are clearly independent, the matrix has rank $3$, and thus also has a unique solution of $(0,-1,0)$

Comment: Can we also say that since each column has a pivotal element so the rank is $3$

Comment: Yes, yes you can

Answer (score 2):

You have $3$ pivot columns so the rank is $3$. Yes you are right in this case,
but the rank number is equal to the number of pivot columns after you make echelon form, not the number of non-zero rows.